# How to Translate Dictionary of Functions

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I struggled to think of a good title here, but hopefully my description makes up for it.

As a hobby side-project, I'm attempting to port an interpreter for a [toy language](https://interpreterbook.com/) (you have to pay for the book, just linking to show where I am coming from) from Go to F#.

This has all gone fine until the point where I am needing to call other functions in a dictionary of functions.

Here's a very simplified example of what the Go code tries to do written in F#:

```
let processA a remainingCharacters =
    1

let processB b remainingCharacters =
    2

let processC c remainingCharacters =
    // this doesn't work, obviously, as funcMap is declared below
    let problem = funcMap.[remainingCharacters.Head]
    3 + problem

// i assume there is a better way of doing this, I'm just not sure what it is
let funcMap = dict[('a', processA); ('b', processB); ('c', processC)]

let processCharacter currentCharacter remainingCharacters =
    let processFunc = funcMap.[currentCharacter]
    processFunc currentCharacter remainingCharacters

let input = ['a'; 'b'; 'a'; 'c']
let processInput() =
    let rec processInputRec currentCharacter (remainingCharacters: char list) sum =
        if remainingCharacters.IsEmpty then
            sum
        else
            let currentValue = processCharacter currentCharacter remainingCharacters
            processInputRec remainingCharacters.Head remainingCharacters.Tail (sum + currentValue)
    processInputRec input.Head input.Tail 0

let result = processInput()
sprintf "%i" result |> ignore
```

So basically, it is trying to map given input values to different functions and in certain cases, needing to refer back to that mapping (or at least getting at another one of those mapped functions) inside those functions.

How would I go about doing that in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of compilation in F# is a feature, not a bug. It helps to make sure that your code is not spaghetti, that all dependencies are nice and linear.

The "loopback" scenarios like this one are usually solved via parametrization.

So in this particular case, if you want the specific functions to call `processCharacter` recursively, just pass it in:

```
let processA a remainingCharacters _ =  // an extra unused parameter here
    1

let processB b remainingCharacters _ =  // and here
    2

let processC c remainingCharacters procChar = // here is where the extra parameter is used
    let problem = procChar (List.head remainingCharacters) (List.tail remainingCharacters)
    3 + problem

...    

let rec processCharacter currentCharacter remainingCharacters =
    let processFunc = funcMap.[currentCharacter]
    processFunc currentCharacter remainingCharacters processCharacter
```

---

Note, however, that, although this will solve your immediate problem, this will (probably) not work all the way, because you're not keeping track of which characters got consumed from the input. So that, if `processC` decides to process one more character, the surrounding code won't know about it, and upon return from `processC` will process the same character again. I'm not sure if this was your intent (hard to tell from the code), and if it was, please disregard this warning.

The usual approach to parsing a stream of inputs like this is to have each processing function return a pair - the result of the processing *plus* the tail of remaining inputs, e.g.:

```
let processA chars = 
    1, (List.tail chars)
```

Then the surrounding "driver" function would thread the returned tail of the list to the next processing function. This way, each processing function can consume not necessarily one, but any number of inputs - from zero to all of them.

This approach has been implemented in libraries, too. Take a look at [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/).

---

Another note: your code seems very un-F#-y. You're not using many F# features, making your code longer and more complicated than it needs to be. For example, instead of accessing `.Tail` and `.Head`, it is customary to pattern-match on the list:

```
let rec processInputRec current rest sum =
    match rest with
    | [] -> sum
    | (next, rest') ->
        let currentValue = processCharacter current rest
        processInputRec next rest' (sum + currentValue)
```

Comment: Thanks, I fully appreciate that the ordering is a feature and not a bug; I was just mentally stuck trying to work around my default OOP way of thinking. I had started down the path of adding the appropriate function as a parameter but wasn't sure if that would be tenable. You are exactly right about handling those functions that process more than one character of input and my actual implementation already does return both the "result" and the "new remaining" input.

Comment: Also thanks for the reminder about the pattern matching, this example was something I wrote free-hand but you are right that I was making things more verbose than I needed to.